# emoji can't rotate with canvas when text include emoji

Tags: android

I am rotating and scaling canvas using `canvas.setMatrix()` and then drawing text on canvas using `canvas.drawText();`. That's working as expected. But when I try to draw text that contains emojis (android device's default emojis), they don't get rotated. Everything else in the text gets rotated as expected. Also drawing and scaling works as expected for emojis, it's just the rotating that doesn't work，and I find it only appears in android7.0 or below 7.0.

```
 public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mText)) {
      drawCursor(canvas);
      return;
    }
    float allTextHeight = mTextLineHeight * mLines.length;
    float y = (mHeight - allTextHeight) / 2;
    float offset = mPaint.getFontMetrics().ascent;
    canvas.save();
      canvas.translate(mWidth / 2, 0);
      float initY = y;
      for (String line : mLines) {
        drawText(canvas, line, 0f, y - offset, mPaint, initY);
        y += mTextLineHeight;
      }
    canvas.restore();
  }
```

Comment: show some codes here @无问西东

Comment: ok,please help me.

Comment: when the text include emoji,only text can rotate with canvas,emoji can't rotate,but can scale.